# Change size of bubble radius without changing r value

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm adding data points to a bubble graph. However, since the value for r is very small I can barely see the points on the graph. I tried to use the radius property to expand the radius, but it seems to be overwritten by the r data property. How can I increase the radius for each bubble? For example, how can I set them to 10x the actual r value?

This is the code that I have so far:

```
    this.managers.forEach(manager => {
        const newDataPoint = {
            label: [manager.SecurityName],
            backgroundColor: this.getRandomRGB(),
            borderColor: this.getRandomRGB(),
            data: [{
                x: +manager[this.selectedX],
                y: +manager[this.selectedY],
                r: +manager[this.selectedR]
            }],
            radius: (+manager[this.selectedR] * 10)
        };
        this.chartDataSet.push(newDataPoint);
    });
```

I've managed to change the size by multiplying the r property directly, but that changes the actual value that shows up when hovered, which I want to avoid. How can I keep the r property the same but still increase the radius?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api). The API offers different hooks that may be used for executing custom code. In your case, you could use the `afterDatasetUpdate` hook  to increase the radius of the points in the dataset's [metadata](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#getdatasetmetaindex).

```
plugins:[{
  afterDatasetUpdate: chart => {
    chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data.forEach(v => {
      v._model.radius *= 10;
      v._options.hoverRadius = v._model.radius;
    })
  }
}],
```

```js
new Chart('canvas', {
  type: 'bubble',
  plugins: [{
    afterDatasetUpdate: chart => {
      chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data.forEach(v => {
        v._model.radius *= 10;
        v._options.hoverRadius = v._model.radius;
      })
    }
  }],
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'First Dataset',
      data: [
        {x: 10, y: 20, r: 1 }, 
        {x: 20, y: 10, r: 2 }
      ],
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 5,
          max: 25
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 5,
          max: 25
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" height="90"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

For developers using version 3.9.1 it is like this:

```js
const pixelValue = (scale, v) => {
  const val = scale.getValueForPixel(v)
  return Math.trunc(isNaN(val) ? v * 6 : 3)
}

const $chart = document.getElementById("chart");
const chart = new Chart($chart, {
  type: "bubble",
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: "scaled radius",
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      data: [{
          x: 10,
          y: 11,
          size: 1
        },
        {
          x: 20,
          y: 5,
          size: 3
        }
      ],
      radius: context => {
        const scale = context.chart.scales.y
        const size = context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex].size
        const value = Math.abs(pixelValue(scale, size))

        return value
      },
    }]
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      x: {
        min: 0,
        max: 30
      },
      y: {
        min: 2,
        max: 14
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 180px;
}

canvas {
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="height: 180px; width: 600px">
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-ElRFoEQdI5Ht6kZvyzXhYG9NqjtkmlkfYk0wr6wHxU9JEHakS7UJZNeml5ALk+8IKlU6jDgMabC3vkumRokgJA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```